# Magento Sort Categories Alphabetically

Tags: magento, categories

recently I was asked to display top-level categories and its sub-categories on left navigation in alphabetical order.

The code I'am using is

```
<ul id="demo1" class="nav">
<?php $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categories = $helper->getStoreCategories(); ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $_category): ?>
<?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately it displays the categories but not alphabetically.

Also is it not displaying because I am using category helper function ?

Is there any built-in function to display Categories and its Sub-categories in alphabetical order ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
<?php $categories = $helper->getStoreCategories(); ?>
```

Add:

```
// sorted by name, fetched as collection
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);

// sorted by name, fetched as array
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', false, false);
```

Hope will help!