# Magento sort mobile navigation categories

Tags: php, magento

**Situation**
I have a responsive webshop. When the user is on a mobile phone he still can select which category he wants to navigate to. This is done via a expandable menu. Now I'm trying to organize all the categories on alphabetical order. But I have no idea how I can achieve this. All other answers on stack don't fit my problem.

**Question**
How can I organize the categories alphabetically in the expandable menu?

mobinav.php

```
<?php 
global $var_yttheme;
if ( $var_yttheme->isHomepage() === FALSE ) {
$homecls='class="nav-home"';
} else {
$homecls='class="nav-home active"';
}
if($var_yttheme->getParam("responsive_menu")=='2'){ ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>
</button>
<div id="yt_resmenu_collapse" style="height: 0;" class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav-menu clearfix">
    <li <?php echo $homecls;?>>
        <a <?php echo $homecls;?> href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#yt_resmenu_collapse .nav-menu > li.parent').each(function(){
                $(this).find('> ul').wrap('<div class="res-wrapnav">');
                $(this).append('<span class="menuress-toggle"></span>');
            });
        });
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery('#yt_resmenu_collapse .parent .menuress-toggle').css('height', jQuery('#yt_resmenu_collapse .parent > a').outerHeight());

            jQuery('#yt_resmenu_collapse .parent > .res-wrapnav').each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open')){
                    jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(this).children('ul').height());
                }
            });
            jQuery('#yt_resmenu_collapse .parent .menuress-toggle').click(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('open')){
                    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                    jQuery(this).parent().children('.res-wrapnav').css('height', '0px');
                }else{
                    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('open');
                    jQuery(this).parent().children('.res-wrapnav').css('height', jQuery(this).parent().children('.res-wrapnav').children('ul').height());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php
}elseif($var_yttheme->getParam("responsive_menu")=='3'){ ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>
</button>
<div id="yt_resmenu_sidebar">
    <ul class="nav-menu clearfix">
    <li <?php echo $homecls;?>>
        <a <?php echo $homecls;?> href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>"     title="Home"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('body#bd').append('<div class="yt_ressidebar_screennav"><nav id="yt_screennav"><ul class="siderbar-menu"></ul></nav></div>');
            $('#yt_screennav ul.siderbar-menu').html($('#yt_resmenu_sidebar ul.nav-menu').html());

                $('#yt-responsivemenu .btn.btn-navbar').click(function(){
                    if($('body#bd').hasClass('onpen-sidebar')){
                        $('body#bd').removeClass('onpen-sidebar');
                    }else{
                        $('body#bd').addClass('onpen-sidebar');
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php
}else{
$options = array();
$category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category){
    $catIds[] = $_category->getId();
}
$regexp  = "[0-9/]+(".implode("|", $catIds)."){1}[0-9/]?";
if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {           
    $category_collection->addPathsFilter();
}else{
    $category_collection->addPathFilter($regexp);
}
foreach($category_collection as $category){
    $c = new stdClass();
    $c->label = $category->getName();
    $c->value = $category->getId();
    $c->level = $category->getLevel();
    $c->parentid = $category->getParentId();
    $c->url_path = $category->getUrlPath();
    $c->is_active = false;
    if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
        if($c->value == array_pop($this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds())){
            $c->is_active = true;
        }
    }           
    $cats[$c->value] = $c;
}

foreach($cats as $id => $c){
    if (isset($cats[$c->parentid])){
        if (!isset($cats[$c->parentid]->child)){
            $cats[$c->parentid]->child = array();
        }
        $cats[$c->parentid]->child[] =& $cats[$id];
    }
}
foreach($cats as $id => $c){
    if (!isset($cats[$c->parentid])){
        $stack = array($cats[$id]);
        while( count($stack)>0 ){
            $opt = array_pop($stack);
            $option = array(
                'label' => ($opt->level>2 ? str_repeat('- - ', $opt->level-2) : '') . $opt->label,
                'value' => $opt->value,
                'url_path'  => $opt->url_path,
                'is_active' => $opt->is_active,
            );
            array_push($options, $option);
            if (isset($opt->child) && count($opt->child)){
                foreach(array_reverse($opt->child) as $child){
                    array_push($stack, $child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
unset($cats);
?>
<?php 
if ($var_yttheme->isHomepage()===FALSE) {
    $homecls='';
} else {
    $homecls='selected="selected"';
}
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function MobileRedirectUrl(){
    window.location.href =    document.getElementById("yt_resmenu_selectbox").value;
}
</script>
<div class="menu-selectbox">
<i class="icon-reorder"></i>
<select id="yt_resmenu_selectbox" onchange="MobileRedirectUrl(this);">
<option value="<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>" <?php echo $homecls ?> ><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></option>
<?php foreach ($options as $item): 
if($item['url_path'] != '/root-catalog' && $item['value'] != '1'){
?>
    <option <?php echo ($item['is_active'])?"selected='selected'":"" ?> value="<?php echo ($item['url_path'])?$this->getBaseUrl().$item['url_path']: $item['value'] ?>"><?php echo $item['label'] ?></option>
<?php 
} endforeach ?>
</select>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

with

```
 $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

second solution

```
function compareByName($options, $option) {
  return strcmp($options["label"], $option["label"]);
}
usort($options, 'compareByName');

print_r($options);
```

last solution

```
$category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$category_collection->setOrder('name', 'ASC');
```

replace this

`foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category){`

with

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false) as $_category){
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I replaced as you said but it doesn't make any difference. Here is a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/34128a4ad36b3558ed7ee721a21ca10a.png

Comment: @LarsVelthuis check the second solution

Comment: How can I implement that?

Comment: place it before `foreach ($options as $item):` code

Comment: Doesn't do anything unfortunately. Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/856a505e3e0f301f1570c8e38f4a2519.png

Comment: remove the `print_r($options);` this is for checking the output of new array

Comment: I know, already did that. But doesn't even print the new output.. :(. It also doesn't show the categories in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but even the last solution doesn't make any change at all.

Comment: so i realized after all your solution is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470850/magento-sort-categories-alphabetically replace with them `$this->getStoreCategories()`

Comment: Tried that. Still nothing happened.

Comment: is you cache is disabled in admin panel?? or try to refresh it.

Comment: Cache is disabled. Tried to refresh it but makes no difference.

Comment: try on this code `</li>
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>` last code i place replace with this `foreach`

Comment: Nope does'nt work. That just gives me an empty website :p.

Comment: now you reach the correct place :D go to admin panel and enable template hint and block hint check the block name.

Comment: Haha already did that at the start. The block name is correct. mobinav.phtml

Comment: this is template path not block name. in block name this method is defined `getStoreCategories`

Comment: Just enabled template path hints. This is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/9336c8e7ea97fc933c824462de8a28e5.png

Comment: also enable block hints too you need to do the changes in block now.

Comment: copy `app/code/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation` to  `app/code/Local/Catalog/Block/Navigation` and make the change in required method

Comment: And what should I change in there? Sorry, as I said. First time using php in magento.

Comment: on line `133` replace `return $helper->getStoreCategories();
` with  `return $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false)`;

Comment: Okay I found the navigation.php. But there is no such folder structure in app/code/local/catalog/../../..

Comment: for editing purpose you have to create these folder to make change you cannot change the core file directly it is not good practice.

Comment: mistake `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` this will path to override the file

Comment: this still breaks the site unfortunately.

Comment: try that `return $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, true)`

Comment: Same result. But I've noticed that the left side of the site (when not on mobile, the categories are displayed alphabetical). But when you expand them (via mobile phone), they aren't sorted.

Comment: Think i'm gonna park this problems. Takes too much time right now.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

with

```
$category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

or

```
$category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```